# Is there a difference between initializing a variable using new, followed by assignment and just assignment on initialization?

Tags: java, object, reference

I am trying to learn Java.

I have a custom class, which has attributes:

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
}
```

I have another class, where I do:

```
public class foo{
    private Person guy;

    public void setGuy(Person guy){
        this.guy = guy;
    }

    public Person getGuy(){
        return guy;
    }

    void someMethod(){
        Person anotherGuy = new Person();
        anotherGuy = getGuy();
    }
}
```

I am confused when I use the `getGuy()` method. 
I thought that when I do this:

```
Person anotherGuy = new Person();
anotherGuy = getGuy();
```

I create a new object, which has the same value as guy. But it seems that anotherGuy is actually a pointer to guy.
So

```
Person anotherGuy = getGuy();
```

and the above 2 lines, do the exact same thing? I am confused. Also then how do I create a entirely new object in memory?

Comment: person anotherGuy = new Person(); should be "Person anotherGuy = new Person();" - This is not answer of your question but a suggestion :)

Comment: And return value connote be object in method declaration, so public guy getGuy(), should be public Person getGuy() :) Sorry not being smarts but it's good if you start practising code convention :)

Comment: haha..thanks. Sorry it was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So
>
> ```
> Person anotherGuy = getGuy();
> ```
>
> and the above 2 lines, do the exact same thing?

No, the other version creates a new Person() object first and then discards it (which is just a waste of memory and processor cycles).

Comment: Thanks all for the explanation. So in Java when I assign one object to another, I do it by reference only. To create an entirely new object, I will have to do Object.clone() or something else, am i right?

Comment: Forget Object.clone(), it's broken in most cases (read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch to learn more about that). You create a new Object by using `new SomeObject()`, or a factory method or copy constructor if available.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person anotherGuy;
```

this is a reference to a Person object

```
anotherGuy = new Person();
```

this sets the reference to a new Person object

```
anotherGuy = getGuy();
```

this sets the reference to the same reference as the guy member of foo.

I you want to "copy" object you might want to have a look for Object.clone()

Answer (score 1):

While folks have already talked/explained about the behavior of your existing code, in order to do what you want to, use the `clone` feature in Java, wherein your Person class would implement the `Cloneable` interface, which would ask you to implement the `clone()` method.

Your `clone()` method should like this :

```
public Object clone()
{
   Person p = new Person();
   p.setName(this.name);
   // similarly copy any other properties you want
   return p;
}
```

and then invoke clone to copy your object:

```
Person another = (Person) person.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java variables can only contain primitives and references. `Person` is a reference to an object. (You don't have to use `&` like you might in C++ because its the only option)

When you do

```
Person anotherGuy = new Person(); // create a new object and assign the reference.
anotherGuy = getGuy(); // change the reference in `anotherGuy` to be the one returned by getGuy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both do the same thing, in that after both method calls, `anotherGuy == null`.